# Passing the file path and file name and getting data in SSIS using foreach loop container

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012, ssis-2016

1. Can I do the same without using Foreach loop file enumerator?
2. If I do the automation to pick file using foreach loop file enumerator i am facing errors like:

   Error at Package1: The connection "{5327333C-E737-4D91-B1CF-4B75912D3FEE}" is not found. This error is thrown by Connections collection when the specific connection element is not found.

   Error at Package1: The connection "{5327333C-E737-4D91-B1CF-4B75912D3FEE}" is not found. This error is thrown by Connections collection when the specific connection element is not found.

   Error at Data Flow Task 1 [SSIS.Pipeline]: Cannot find the connection manager with ID "{5327333C-E737-4D91-B1CF-4B75912D3FEE}" in the connection manager collection due to error code 0xC0010009. That connection manager is needed by "Excel Source.Connections[OleDbConnection]" in the connection manager collection of "Excel Source". Verify that a connection manager in the connection manager collection, Connections, has been created with that ID.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.